# Snowflake: REGEX_SUBSTR gives null?

Tags: regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm using a regular expression in Snowflake and am getting a surprising result.  Specifically, I run this:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('https://example.com/a/b/c?name=me', 'https://example.com/a/b/c\?name=\\w+')
```

and I get back `NULL`.

I was expecting to get back the full match (according to the Snowflake docs).  In this case, that would be:

```
'https://example.com/a/b/c?name=me'
```

What am I misunderstanding?

Thanks!

Comment: In a regex pattern, forward slashes need to be escaped. `/` ---> `\/`

Comment: @emsimpson92 So this also gets `NULL`: `SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('https://example.com/a/b/c?name=me', 'https:\/\/example.com\/a\/b\/c\?name=\\w+')`

Comment: [`https:\/\/example\.com\/a\/b\/c\?name=\w+`](https://regex101.com/r/VHttCM/1)

Comment: Seems that the `?` is missing another backslash like you did on `\w+`. `\\?`

Answer (score 0):

as per Matthias's comment, the `?` is a wild card token, so needs escaped, which is a double \ to get \? past the escape encoding. Thus

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('https://example.com/a/b/c?name=me',
            'https:\/\/example.com\/a\/b\/c\\?name=\\w+');
```

will give the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your forward slashes

`SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('https:\/\/example.com\/a\/b\/c\?name=me', 'https:\/\/example.com\/a\/b\/c\?name=\\w+')`